# Force the default ASP.NET core xml serializer to serialize an object with the base class type

Tags: xml, asp.net-core

I have a question regarding the default XML serializer of the ASP.NET Core.

I have the following class structure:

```cs
[XmlRoot("base")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
[Serializable()]
public class Base
{
    [XmlAttribute("propertyA")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    [XmlAttribute("propertyB")]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following configuration for ASP.NET Core

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/xml"));
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
    });
}
```

and I have the following endpoint:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Base obj = new Derived()
    {
        PropertyA = "some text",
        PropertyB = "some other text"
    };
    return Ok(obj);
}
```

As it is the endpoint returns the following XML

```
<Derived xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" propertyA="some text" propertyB="some other text" />
```

Is there a way to force the default XML serializer to serialize the object with the base type? What we would like to have is an XML like the following:

```
<base xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Derived" propertyA="some text" propertyB="some other text" />
```

For example, the following example works as expected:

```cs
void main()
{
    Base obj = new Derived()
    {
        PropertyA = "some text",
        PropertyB = "some other text"
    };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
    var xml = "";
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
        xml = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `public class Base
{
    [XmlAttribute("propertyA")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("propertyB")]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}`?It looks like you only need a base class with both propertyA and propertyB.

Comment: The class structure was based on an XSD that a third party gave us. We actially don't want to make any changes on the generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the Derived class is the father/boss; the full object is on Derived, not in the base, cause you are extending base on Derived. It is the same scenario if you do the following:

```cs
    public class Derived { }
    public class Base : Derived { }
```

In this case, the XML Root must be `Base`, cause `Base` is who has the full object.

If you still want to set `Base` as Root XML I strongly recommend renaming Derived class node name or create your own XmlDocument.

Have a nice coding !!

Comment: Hi @Bryan, thanks for the response. I updated the question because I believe I was not clear of the case.